# Apache routing without htaccess

Tags: apache, routes

I am working with a custom website built in PHP running on Apache server. The client wants to move it to a new server. I moved everything including the .htaccess file, the homepage loads fine but all the other urls like site.com/register isn't working. I'm sure this is not handled by code in the old server because I renamed everything (including .htaccess) and it still works. If I create a file like test.php in the old server, I can access it like site.com/test. It doesn't even hit the index.php file. Also, not all the urls work like this, some are loading through files in other folders.

So my question is - what are the possible ways that Apache can let user access site.com/test without the .php extension. It must not be using .htaccess. Also, we should be able to add exceptions to this so that some urls can be loaded differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve same thing in hosts file if you are using Linux server. you need to define same rules in hosts configuration file.